# SQL - How to retrieve a value that appears at least 5 times in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using an Oracle Database through SQL Navigator and I'm looking to retrieve a value that appears at least 5 times in a column, but can't figure out the exact SQL clause for this..

Hope it's clear enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GROUP BY` on that `Column`, and set the clause `Count() >=5`